# pytest: how to terminate FastAPI TestClient after each test?

Tags: python, websocket, pytest, fastapi, ubuntu-22.04

I am testing FastAPI application that keeps open WebSocket connection forever. By design, only the client is supposed to close WebSocket. After test execution, pytest doesn't finish, it is hanging forever.

1. What's the proper way of testing such an application?
2. Is there any way to terminate the fixture after test execution?

**EDIT 2023-11-29**

This problem happens on Ubuntu 22 (`Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0`, `plugins: respx-0.20.2, anyio-3.7.1, asyncio-0.21.1`).

On Fedora 38 (`platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0`, `plugins: anyio-3.7.1, asyncio-0.21.1, respx-0.20.2`) pytest exits correctly.

It's interesting that the same plugins are printed in different order on these systems.

Example:

```
$ pytest -k test_comedy_tom_hanks_async
======================================================================= test session starts ========================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0 -- /home/gbajson/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/vox-fdgLK-f1-py3.11/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /storage/amoje/Sync/area22/vox-async
configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: timeout-2.1.0, anyio-3.7.1, asyncio-0.21.1
asyncio: mode=Mode.STRICT
collected 13 items / 9 deselected / 4 selected                                                                                                                     
run-last-failure: no previously failed tests, not deselecting items.

src/tests/test_main.py::test_comedy_tom_hanks_async[asyncio+uvloop-3200.0-0.1] PASSED 


<<< HANGING FOREVER >>>
```

Here is my fixture used for testing:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="websocket")
async def fixture_ws_audio():
    client = TestClient(app)
    with client.websocket_connect("/ws/audio") as websocket:
        yield websocket
```

I already tried:

- `@pytest.mark.timeout(20)`
- I added the following fixture to execute some actions after each test, but `pytest` never reaches `logger.info("Test finished.")`

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def run_before_and_after_tests():
    """Fixture to execute asserts before and after a test is run"""
    # Setup: fill with any logic you want
    logger.info("Starting test.")
    yield  # this is where the testing happens
    logger.info("Test finished.")
```

**EDIT 2023-10-09**

Both, backend and test code, use `asyncio.to_thread` calls, example:

```
        try:
            coro = asyncio.to_thread(read_from_ws, websocket)
            coro_waited = asyncio.wait_for(coro, timeout)
            results = await asyncio.gather(coro_waited)
            text = results[0]

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            logger.info("asyncio.TimeoutError: text: %s", text)
            break
```

When I terminate pytest session after executing all tests I see:

```
======== 4 passed, 5 deselected in 77.85s (0:01:17) ========
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1553, in _shutdown
    atexit_call()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 31, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1112, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1132, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Comment: Seems like  the `websocket` connection is open after the test function is completed, and `pytest` waits for all fixtures to finalize before exiting.

Comment: @underflow yes, you are right, and this is expected behaviour of the application. Client opens a persistent WebSocket connection and from time to time executes some actions. I'd like to test particular actions. Server is not supposed to close WebSocket. WebSocket should be closed only by client.

Comment: @gbajson could you also provide the test code and the application code that handles the websocket connection? Are there multiple threads involved? What happens if the websocket connection is closed from the client side?

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a issue of  the `websocket` connection is open after the test function is completed, and `pytest` waits for all fixtures to finalize before exiting.

The TestClient's websocket_connect method returns a context manager that, when used with the with statement, will close the websocket`connection upon exiting. However, since you are using it in a fixture with yield, the websocket is not getting closed untill all the tests that use the fixture have completed.`
One approach to fix this is to use FastAPI`'s dependency injection system to ensure that the websocket is closed once the test finishes. For example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="websocket")
async def fixture_ws_audio():
    client = TestClient(app)
    websocket = client.websocket_connect("/ws/audio")
    yield websocket
    await websocket.close()
```

By adding the await websocket.close() line after the yield, you're making sure that the websocket connection gets closed once the test is done.

you can also use `request.addfinalizer`, a method to add cleanup code for fixtures.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="websocket")
def fixture_ws_audio(request):
    client = TestClient(app)
    websocket = client.websocket_connect("/ws/audio")
    def fin():
        await websocket.close()
    request.addfinalizer(fin)  # adding a finalizer to close the websocket
    return websocket
```

Comment: According to the [documenation](https://www.starlette.io/testclient/#establishing-a-test-session), "`websocket_connect()` must be used as a context manager (in a with block).". The `__enter__` method does a lot more than simply returning `self`, and `__exit__` calls `close` anyways. Also, your assumption about the fixture only being executed once for all tests is wrong because it is function-scoped.

Comment: Thanks! Probably, I wasn't clear. I didn't assume that fixture is executed only once for all tests. I need it for each test, therefore I used `scope="function"`.
I am still looking for the proper way to investigate what's hanging, pytests already informs me that test PASSED, so I am assuming that it is something in pytest execution environment rather than in the application code itself.